# AngularJS variable to html <object> attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5-video

I want to set part of an url of an html `<object>` tag with an angular variable, but I get a lot of error messages in the console, because the presented string looks like

```
http://...../%7B%7Bvarname%7B%7B/....
```

I had the same problem with the `<img>` tag, but there I could use the `ng-src` directive. I guess I need to write my own directive, but what are the things I need to look out for?

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://...?chan={{varname}}" bgcolor="#000000">
    ...
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=...&chan={{varname}}" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<object ... data="{{address}}">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.varname = "something";
$scope.address = "http://...?chan=" + $scope.varname;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G765D/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but should this work? Because for me it does exactly what I expected, nothings gets "interpreted". The final html output includes {{'http://...?chan='+varname}} and of course the error message stays the same.

Comment: @KenavR `varname` should be a scope model. Take a look at my update.

Comment: @KenavR Try storing the entire address in a scope variable and then using that inside the HTML.

Comment: It always was a $scope variable and I can correctly output it with {{varname}}, but as an attribute value it doesn't work. It does get correctly "interpreted" eventually, but the browser is faster fetching the markup, than angular is with replacing the {{variables}}. (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) I guess I need to dig more into ngSrc and go on with my search.

Comment: Did you try with my latest update? By having the entire address in a scope variable instead of concatenating in the HTML?

Comment: Yes I did, the error message changed, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @KenavR I have added a fiddle which works regardless of the approach used! :D

Comment: Thanks, I changed your fiddle example with my resources to show you that it doesn't work, but ... it does work, I am very surprised. I thought the reason was that I use Angular 1.1.5 and you 1.2.2, but regardless it works. I need to take a deeper look into the rest of my code, I may be back later.